# Can I post a software concept here?

Tags: discussion

I decided to post this here because this is more of a Stack Overflow question than a programming question.

I wrote a concept for a piece of software (specifically related to Penetration Testing, and system administration) with images made with [Balsamiq Mockups 3](https://balsamiq.com/). But before I start coding I want to get opinions on it, what language would be best, and if there is even an audience for it.

My question is, can I post the concept here? Under the programming version of course. If not, then where can i post it?

I have looked everywhere I could think of. I searched Google several times, here on Stack Overflow, and even searched Quora and Ask.

Comment: maybe here? http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, that isn't an appropriate question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Then where could i post said post?

Comment: @AustinSmith this isn't a clearinghouse for the rest of the internet! It's certainly not on topic anywhere on this network, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: do you know where i might could post it? Another website? A forum?

Comment: @AustinSmith *"this isn't a clearinghouse for the rest of the internet"*

Comment: That still doesn't answer my question. Also, it will not let me @ you for some reason.

Comment: @AustinSmith it answers the first half; the second half is off-topic, for the reason I've given twice now. You don't need to tag me, I get notified because I wrote the answer.

Comment: Ehh.. Fair enough i guess. Though i was looking for this all day yesterday, and found nothing. Does SO really not have a off-topic place to post random crap? I mean, they have a huge network i just figured that would exist.

Comment: Quora might be worth a try (although the quality of answers received may vary)

Comment: @Pekka I Checked Quora. I said so in my post. Though, my question was limited to be very short.

Comment: You said you *searched* Quora, not that you posted your question there?

Comment: @AustinSmith just because it's off topic here does not obligate us to keep a running list of all other locations on the internet and what is on topic for each of them. Not sure how this is unexpected.

Comment: Reddit /r/programming YMMV

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I did post to Reddit [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/softwaredevelopment/comments/524uxy/would_you_use_this_pentestingsystemadmin_toolkit/) but i had to post in SoftwareDevelopment because the programming and hacking side did not allow detailed questions, just short questions like on Quora. And thuss, i have had no reply's to said topic because its misplaced.

Comment: @AustinSmith on redit it says it was posted a day ago, i don't see any comments and now it just says removed but unless someone did said it was misplaced then removed the comment you need to give it time since 24 hours ago was a sunday afternoon for me and i'm like....almost 17 hours ahead of the US. you need to give it time people because people have different habits for the internet such as when they go on and stuff

Comment: @memor it was moved [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/softwaredevelopment/comments/524uxy/would_you_use_this_pentestingsystemadmin_toolkit/) for some reason..